# GravityForms - List Field with DropDown on entries column

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, layout-gravity

I use GravityForms List field. I use multiple columns on this list fields.
My question is : for one column, can I get a drop-down with multiples choices ?

I can implement it in PHP but no idea for API to use. In fact I want just transform a textbox field in dropdown. Have you got an idea ?

You can see that I want here :
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/854196c20150309154121.jpg

Answer (score 9):

There is a filter you can use:

```
add_filter( 'gform_column_input_187_1_1', 'set_column', 10, 5 );
function set_column( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
    return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => 'First Choice,Second Choice' );
}
```

More deets: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_column_input/#examples

Comment: this one should be marked as best answer. The plugin is deprecated by now, so. this is the best solution