# GravityForms - List Field with multiple DropDown on entries column

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms, add-filter

I have a list in Gravity forms created with 3 columns, but need the first column to be text, the second to be a drop-down with 3 options and also the third column to be a drop-down with 3 options. I can get the second column to be a drop-down, but fail to get the third.

Using this post: [GravityForms - List Field with DropDown on entries column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205256/gravityforms-list-field-with-dropdown-on-entries-column/58121980#58121980) - I can get the following code to work:

```
add_filter( 'gform_column_input_1_27_2', 'set_column', 10, 5 );
function set_column( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
    return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => 'Fluent,Adequate,Basic' );
}
```

But if I add the code again and set the ID to gform_column_input_1_27_3 to get the following:

```
add_filter( 'gform_column_input_1_27_2', 'set_column', 10, 5 );
function set_column( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
    return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => 'Fluent,Adequate,Basic' );
}

add_filter( 'gform_column_input_1_27_3', 'set_column', 10, 5 );
function set_column( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => 'Fluent,Adequate,Basic' );
}
```

It returns an error:

```
Cannot redeclare set_column() (previously declared in wp-content/themes/xxxxxx/functions.php:40)
```

Can someone explain how do I get the third column to display a dropdown like the second does? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the `set_columns()` function twice.

If they will both have the same choices, you could write it like this so that both filters call the same function (without declaring it again):

```
add_filter( 'gform_column_input_1_27_2', 'set_column', 10, 5 );
add_filter( 'gform_column_input_1_27_3', 'set_column', 10, 5 );
function set_column( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
    return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => 'Fluent,Adequate,Basic' );
}
```

If you need different choices for the second, you can rename the second function:

```
add_filter( 'gform_column_input_1_27_2', 'set_column', 10, 5 );
function set_column( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
    return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => 'Fluent,Adequate,Basic' );
}

add_filter( 'gform_column_input_1_27_3', 'set_column2', 10, 5 );
function set_column2( $input_info, $field, $column, $value, $form_id ) {
return array( 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => 'One,Two,Three' );
}
```